# PyQt4 QMainWindow with different view's as QWidget

Tags: user-interface, pyqt4, qwidget, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I am new to PyQt4 and i try to make a QMainWindow in which I can change the views. I use the QtDesigner plugin for eclipse. I make a QMainWindow with some space for a view. The view is a QWidget made in QtDesigner, too.

So how can i show my QWidget in my QMainWindow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `QWidget` is just a blank, frameless rectangle that is usually used as a container for other widgets - so it won't really "show" anything. What were you expecting to see? And what do you mean by "change the views"?

Comment: I want to show datas. my idea is that i have different QWidgets with different methods to show (QTable, QListview, etc.) and the user can chose how he wants to see the datas. That i dont had to change the hole QMainWindow i want QWidgets which i can add and drop from my QMainWindow.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to put your different "views" in either a [Tab Widget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtabwidget.html#details) or a [Stacked Widget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html#details).

The [Config Dialog Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/dialogs-configdialog.html) gives a relatively simple example of how to use a stacked widget, and a python version of it is included in the PyQt demo and examples.

(If you don't have the demos and examples available on your system, they can be obtained from the [PyQt sources](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)).